# CartoDB import defaults to string

Tags: carto, csv, import

When uploading CSV files to CartoDB through their web interface, all columns default to string as their data type, despite the CSV file containing a number of number-only columns. An example row is

`1400000US55025000100,55025000100,"Census Tract 1, Dane County, Wisconsin",1401,118,1070,128,903,136,167,82,131,62,36,34,0,9,179,74,179,74,0,9,0,9,0,9,0,9,36,31,35,28,6,11,75,45`

I know I can change the data type in the table editor, but when you have a large number of columns, this becomes very tedious. According to their documentation, CartoDB should automatically assigns the right data type. Any advice on how to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSV does not have the concept of data types and that's why CartoDB tries to guess the type of the column. In any case CartoDB can not have a 100% success rate.

if you want to ensure your data types are kept use a format that allow data types (geojson, shp for example)

In this case I think it's a problem with ogr2ogr (the tool we use under the hood to process files). I reported this as a bug https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb/issues/2600 so you can track it

Comment: Thanks! I'll follow your bug report on GitHub and for now just change the data types manually/with SQL.